# Can't connect to VM because inbound port rule is not working

Tags: azure-virtual-machine

I'm having trouble connecting to my Azure VM, despite trying to restart it and creating new instances. The DenyAllInbound rule was preventing me from connecting to my VMs before because the RDP rule that's supposed to override it wouldn't get added at all. Today Azure is creating the RDP rule for me, as it should, however, I was only able to connect once, and it hasn't been working since then. Also, that was a different VM. I had to delete it because while creating the VM, Azure changed the region without telling me and as a result, there was very high latency. Any suggestions on how to fix this issue?

[image]

I'm getting this error:
[image]

I tried:

1. Restarting the vm
2. Creating a new vm
3. Creating a new RDP rule with high priority
4. Tried changing the port, but apparently 3389 is the only option for RDP

Update:
[image]

Comment: Kindly share the error, what you are getting while connecting to RDP.

Comment: @VenkatV I've added a screenshot of the error

Comment: Q: Can you change (or delete) the offending rule without needing a GUI (without needing remote desktop access)?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/manage-network-security-group?tabs=network-security-group-portal

Comment: Kindly let me know on which network you are trying to connect to the VM, whether it is from Office Network (office Laptop) or Home Network (Personal Laptop) and also check the VM Running Status by going to Boot Diagnostics.
If you are facing the issue from office Network, try to connect from Personal Network and share the result.

Comment: @VenkatV Turns it out was an issue with my wifi. I can connect to vm using mobile data but not using wifi. Come to think of it, the one time I managed to connect to one of my vm's was when I was using mobile data. I can switch to wifi once I'm in the vm though. There are some certificate issues (see pic) and I guess that's why my wifi is not allowing me to connect to the vm.

Comment: @paulsm4 I can edit and delete the rules from the azure dashboard without needing to be in the vm. That didn't really change anything though. Still can't connect using wifi. I'm on institute wifi btw (National Knowledge Network - nkn.gov.in)

Answer (score 1):

You can check **Azure VM RDP** connectivity issues by following the steps.

1. Check the VM running status by navigating to **Boot diagnostics** as it displays the current screen of **Azure VM**.

[image]

3. To collect Azure VM diagnostics install the **AzurePerformanceDiagnostics** extension as below.

**Azure VM > Extensions + applications > Add.**

[image]

[image]

Run the **VM diagnostics** to collect VM information.

[image]

Once complete the diagnostics, download the report and analyse the issue.

[image]

3. Run **Network security group** test as below.

[image]

4. If still persisting the issue, kindly check with a different **Network** without any blockage.

Refer : [Troubleshoot Remote Desktop connections to an Azure virtual machine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/virtual-machines/troubleshoot-rdp-connection) more about **Azure VM RDP** issue.

Comment: Good troubleshooting but doesn't solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

I've got a deny all rule which is a default hardcoded rule showing under diagnostics but my metric for the inbound port 3389 is 100  - can someone explain why I can't RDP to the VM?

It all looks fine

[image]